# How to download Griffon distribution in Intellij Gradle project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle, griffon

I am trying to start a Griffon project. The Griffon repository is available from bintray. I created a Gradle project in Intellij and added the maven repository provided into the build.gradle file. But the project structure is not being generated. I need to know how create a Griffon project in Intellij correctly. I am adding the code from the build.gradle file that i edited.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
mavenCentral()

   maven {
      url  "http://dl.bintray.com/griffon/griffon"
  }
}

dependencies {
 testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the instructions found at http://griffon-framework.org/ and  http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html.

Note that IntelliJ includes a Griffon plugin that works with Griffon 1.x but **does not** work with Griffon 2.x. Griffon 2 can be opened/imported as a normal Gradle or Maven project.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am working in a windows environment. The problem is all instructions are Linux specific. It would be helpful if you direct me towards some windows specific instructions. I don't have previous experience working with Gradle or such project management tools so its a bit hard for me to understand right away! hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: The only UNIX specific settings are the usage of $USER_HOME. Change that to %USER_HOME% and it should work.